# JwtTokenSecurity expires when it doesn't have to

Tags: c#, jwt, blazor-webassembly

This is the error message: errorSystem.ArgumentException: 'IDX12401: Expires: '14/11/2022 04:23:03' must be after NotBefore: '14/11/2022 08:03:03'.' The first time is ok, but i dont now why goes 4 hours forward.

I set the `JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY_MINS` with 20 minutes:
This is my class:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationManager
    {
        public const string JWT_SECURITY_KEY = "amg12PLy8BMF43kj9Jj90mahBASvty10MlkqwA31";
        private const int JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY_MINS = 20;
        private IUsuarioService _usuarioService;
        public JwtAuthenticationManager(IUsuarioService usuarioService)
        {
            _usuarioService = usuarioService;
        }

        public UserSession? GenerateJwtToken(string userName, string password)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                return null;
            }

            //Validando credenciales
            var userAccount = _usuarioService.GetByName(userName);
            if(userAccount.Name ==null || userAccount.Password != password) 
            {
                return null;
            }
            //Obtenemos el rol
            RoleDTO rol = _usuarioService.GetRolByUser(userAccount);
            //Generando token jwt
            var tokenExpiryTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY_MINS);
            var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JWT_SECURITY_KEY);
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userAccount.Name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, rol.Role),
            });
            var signingCredential = new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
            var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = claimsIdentity,
                Expires= tokenExpiryTimeStamp,
                SigningCredentials= signingCredential
                
            };

            var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);// on this line the error occurs
            var token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

            //Retornando la sesion de usuario UserSession
            var userSession = new UserSession
            {
                UserName = userAccount.Name,
                Role = rol.Role,
                Token= token,
                ExpiresIn = (int)tokenExpiryTimeStamp.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds,
            };

            return userSession;
        }
    }
```

This is my user session class:

```
public class UserSession
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpiryTimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is data type of usserAccount:

```
public class UserDTO
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public Guid RolId { get; set; }
    }
```

I dont know what is wrong, i used the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7P_eyz4mEmA

Comment: FYI [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokendescriptor.expires?view=azure-dotnet) says that the `Expires` value should be UTC. Is `DateTime.Now` UTC on the system where the code is running? Either way, you should probably use `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: I changed to  DateTime.UtcNow and it worked, thanks!